# Call or Uncall function after resize or orientation changee

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm working on a mobile web project that goes between a two column or single column view based on screen size. For some device sizes, changing from portrait to landscape switches you between the single and double column. Across the bottom of the page there are three feature images that are side by side for two column view, but we want to turn into a content slider in single column.

My issue: 

The javascript conditional I have calls the function when the width of the screen is below a certain width. However if you change the orientation/size of the screen, it doesn't recall the function or re-evaluate the screen width.

What I have:

```
if( $(window).width() < 570) { 
    $(window).load(function() { 
        $('.flexslider').flexslider(); 
    }); 
}
```

What is the best way to watch for resize and call/recall the function after the resize event?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery resize event on window. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZzKy/1/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 //your code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from what Shusl said, you need to create the functions within $(window).resize();

What I would do is create the function and be sure to trigger it too. So it would be something like  -

```
$(window)resize(function() {

    winWidth = $(window).width();
    winHeight = $(window).height();

    if (winWidth < 570) {

       $(window).load(function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider(); });

    }
   else {
      // do something else
   } 

   }).trigger("resize");
```